# How to explicitly open the signature preview window when not completing?

Tags: autocompletion, ctags, previewwindow

When using `<c-x><c-o>`, vim opens a signature preview window which is different from the one opened when using `:ptag`.

How to open that one when not completing like when reviewing in normal mode?

I don't want the full file for preview like with `:ptag`. Just the signature and some type metadata from tags.

I set `omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete`. Not using any completion plugins.

Comment: Which filetype? This is usually a documentation popup. It usually only appears when preview is in completeopt.

Comment: filetype C. Yes completeopt has preview by default.

Comment: Are you *sure* that’s what omnifunc is set to? I ask only because the default filetype uses a special c completion function. At any rate, the best bet is probably Man for stdlib functions. I think some of the code is hardwired in there, especially when completing tags.

Comment: yes you are right. It is `ccomplete#Complete`. I am still not able to find the code that opens that preview window.

Comment: The function `ccomplete#Complete` doesn't seem to read `completeopt` or open preview window by itself. May be some autocommand is doing this.

Comment: No, I believe it’s vim internals. Ie something in the C source. You’ll have better luck asking them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `:set cot=`. To know more info see [cot](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27cot%27)

Answer (score 0):

The way that "signature window", really "preview window", works is this:

- The `:help 'omnifunc'`, if there is one, returns a list of dictionaries, one for each completion suggestion.
- Those dictionaries *can* have a non-mandatory `info` field that contains the text to display in the preview window if `preview` is in `:help 'completeopts'`.
- The preview window is triggered automatically when `completeopts` contains `preview` **AND** when the info field is populated.

In this case, that `info` field is populated on the fly by `ccomplete#Complete()`, with info gathered from tags, files, etc.. It is the value of that field that is displayed in the preview window and there is currently no built-in way to get that exact text in a preview window or elsewhere without using omni-completion.

Now, all the code used to generate that `info` field is under `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/ccomplete.vim` (and it even has been rewritten in vim9script) so it should be doable to cobble something up out of it.